# How to fixed an error message : "trying to access array offset on value of type null." at a $record syntax?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to display an id number from "kategori_barang" table. When I submitted the code, I get an error message which says "trying to access array offset on the value of type null". Somebody can figure this out? Thanks for the help.

```
//the title
<h3>Form Edit Kategori</h3>

//syntax for open a controller 
<?php echo form_open('kategori/edit'); ?>
 
//list for display an id number
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $record['kategori_id'];?>" name="id">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Nama Kategori</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="kategori" placeholder="kategori" 
                   value="<?php echo $record['nama_kategori'];?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Where `$record` is declare?

Comment: I've declare from a controller part :

Comment: function edit()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                //proses kategori
                $this->model_kategori->post();
                redirect('kategori');
            }
            else{
                $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
                echo $id;
                $data['record'] = $this->model_kategori->get_one($id)->row_array();
                $this->load->view('kategori/form_edit', $data);
            }
        }

Comment: And I have a model. Iam using codeigniter

Comment: function edit()
    {
        $data = array(
            'nama_kategori'=> $this->input->update('kategori')
                );
        $this->db->where('kategori_id', $this->input->post(id));
        $this->db->update('kategori_id', $data);
        
    }

Comment: check what is the result of print_r($record);

Answer (score 0):

the error means that your $record array has no such key.
either use

```
isset($record['kategori_id']) ? $record['kategori_id'] : 0;
```

or dump the $record to logs to see what is inside like this

```
error_log( print_r($record, TRUE) );
```

and take it from there....it looks like your $record has nothing in it